# Make my app-service trusted for an Azure API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, fhir-server-for-azure

Im not sure im using the correct terms to describe my issue in the title.

I have setup an Azure API for FHIR in the Azure portal and can't get a grip on how to make my other app-service in Azure "trusted". The app-service in this case is my frontend and i need be able to make some kind of configuration so that my app-service can send request to the Azure API for FHIR. I have been reading the documentation provided when installing the Azure API to FHIR but cant really understand it, i guess this is because im new to everything concerning tokens and auth etc...

So how should i config my Azure API for FHIR and my app-service to be able to do this?

Sorry for the messy explanation hopefully you can get a grasp of what i mean.

Thank you

Comment: Hey Jagge, Microsoft has how-to guides on how to implement client applications to for access to FHIR. Please see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/register-public-azure-ad-client-app

Is there anything that's missing in regards to the how-to guide?